# Update cart total programmatically in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I want to update my cart total in the checkout page by a certain percentage. Like in custom PHP, `$cart = $cart_total - ($cart_total * 0.15);` 
I have wrote the following in functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total', 'custom_cart_total' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals', 'custom_cart_total' );

function custom_cart_total($discount_percentage) {
// actual cart amount is = $195.00
// $discount_percentage = 0.15;
$actual = WC()->cart->total;
WC()->cart->total =+ (WC()->cart->total *= $discount_percentage);
WC()->cart->total =- WC()->cart->total + $actual;

echo $ordertotal = wp_kses_data( WC()->cart->get_total() ); //die();
// $ordertotal is showing the expected amount $165.75;
return WC()->cart->total += $ordertotal; // It shows the $195.00
exit();
}
```

The cart still shows $195.00 but it should be $165.75;
How can I modify the functionality?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec The project was abounded by my client and hence I have not tested your submitted code. However, I'm giving you one upvote but unable to click the same as correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the right hook… try the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'custom_calculated_total', 10, 2 );
function custom_calculated_total( $total, $cart ){
    return round( $total - ($total * 0.15), $cart->dp );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.